# Approximating arbitrary distribution by finite distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

if I'm given two iid random variables $U$ and $V$ having distribution $D$, say, how can I construct iid *finite discrete* random variables $U'$ and $V'$ such that
$$| \mathbb{P}(|U-V|\le 1)- \mathbb{P}(|U'-V'|\le 1)|<\epsilon,$$
for some given $\epsilon>0$?

My idea is to sample $U$ many times and to then define a finite random variable $U'$ by making the observed values of $U$ equiprobable. Sampling it often enough should make the distributions converge, but I absolutely can't make this rigorous.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Answer changed completely to answer the right question.

For some positive integer $M$, let
$$
U_M = \begin{cases}
M & \mbox{if } U'\ge M\\
-M & \mbox{if }U' \le -M\\
\lfloor 2^M U\rfloor\cdot2^{-M} & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Note that $U_M$ only takes finitely many values, and as long as $|U|\le M$, the difference $|U-U_M|$ will be less than $2^{-M}$. Thus, as $M\to\infty$, $U_M$ converges to $U$ with probability one. If we define $V_M$ similarly, this means that $U_M-V_M\to U-V$ almost surely, which implies that $P(
U_M-V_M|\le 1)\to P(|U-V|\le 1)$. Thus, letting $U'=U_M$ and $V'=V_M$ for large enough $M$ will work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'm very sorry though, but I think I used the slightly wrong word... :-( By finite, I meant that $U'$ only takes a _finite_ number of values, i.e. that $U'$ is discrete and moreover finite. That's also why I wrote about sampling $U$ over and over. So sorry!!!

Comment: Do you have any idea about how to tackle the corrected version of the problem?